# How to draw NSRect in a new location

Tags: swift, xcode, appkit

I am a newbie to Swift coding

Below is a custom view class:

```
class MyView: NSView {
   var xloc = 0.0
   var yloc = 0.0
   var width = 400.0
   var height = 200.0
   var myRect = NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 400.0, height: 200.0)
   
   ...

   override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
       let myColor = NSColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: self.alpha)
       myColor.setFill()
       dirtyRect.fill()

       self.myRect = NSRect(x: self.xloc, y: self.yloc, width: self.width, height: self.height)
       self.setNeedsDisplay(myRect)     
       self.myRect.fill(using: NSCompositingOperation.clear)
   }
```

The view controller has a keyDown handler as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
        self.keyDown(with: $0)
        return $0
    }
}

override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let theView = self.view as! MyView
    if event.keyCode == 126 {
        NSLog("Increasing Y coordinate")
        theView.yloc = theView.yloc + 10
        self.view.display()
    }
}
```

Below is the AppDelegate.swift's content:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    
    let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first
    window?.isOpaque = false
    window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    window?.ignoresMouseEvents = true
    window?.toggleFullScreen(self)
    
    window?.collectionBehavior = NSWindow.CollectionBehavior.fullScreenPrimary
    let screenFrame = NSScreen.main?.frame
    
    window?.setFrame(screenFrame!, display: true)
    
    let myView = MyView()
    window?.contentView = myView
    
}
```

The rectangular hole is seen on the screen initially

The above handler is called whenever I press the up arrow key. The self.view.display() in turn calls the draw() method on the view. But the NSRect is not drawn in the new position

Not sure what is wrong

Comment: I tried your code and the rect moves up. `draw` shouldn't call `setNeedsDisplay` but your code works. How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks, Willeke. I have just uploaded the code to Github: https://github.com/suchindrac/hide_pane_mac. The idea is to make a pane that is semi-transparent, that can be moved across. When I execute it from my xcode, pressing the keys doesn't move the NSRect

Comment: Post a [mre] in the question please.

Comment: Oh sorry. I have updated the query with the details of all three files - AppDelegate.swift, MyView.swift, and ViewController.swift

Comment: `window?.contentView = myView` replaces the view in the window. The `ViewController` is moving the rect in the old view.